# php - send variable to next page by link

Tags: php

I need help.

How can I call the variable(within the url) after a successful search result in my index.php to the next page view.php so that I can view the complete data of the variable?

heres my code

"index.php"

```
<form method="post" action="index.php?go" id="searchform">
<input type="text" name="name" size = "50">
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEARCH">
<button type="reset" value="Reset">RESET</button>
</form>


<?php

    $db=mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "") or die ('I cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error()); 
    $mydb=mysql_select_db("emp_dbA");

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_GET['go'])){
    if(preg_match("/[A-Z | a-z]+/", $_POST['name'])){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $letter=$_GET['by'];

    $sql="SELECT emp_ID, fname, lname,mname FROM emp_tbl WHERE fname LIKE '%" . $name . "%' OR lname LIKE '%" . $name ."%' OR mname LIKE '%" .$name . "%'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);  
    $numrows=mysql_num_rows($result);

    echo "<p>" .$numrows . " results found for " . stripslashes($name) . "</p>"; 

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $fname =$row['fname'];
    $mname =$row['mname'];
    $lname=$row['lname'];
    $ID=$row['emp_ID'];

        echo "<ul>\n"; 
        echo "<li>" . "<a href=\"view.php?id=$fname\">"  .$fname . " " . $mname. " " . $lname . "</a></li>\n";
        echo  "</ul>";
                                            }
                                                    }
        else{
        echo "<p>Please enter a search query</p>";
            }


                            }
    }
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the URL parameters with the $_GET environment variable, while the field you did put inside the form (given that you chose `post` as the form method) will be read like `$_POST["name"]`.

As a little piece of advice, try to resort to the GET method as few times as possible. Parameters received with the GET method are seen in the URL, while parameters received from the POST method aren't.

And, of course, sanitize all your GET/POST data before actually using it.

Answer (score 1):

By using the reserved variable `$_GET`

```
$_GET['id']
```

[REFERENCE](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Comment: make sure to filter all input from external sources. If these are numbers, simply cast them to int and be done.

$id = (int)$_GET["id"];

edit: sry, you already covered filtering ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use GET or POST to send data to the next page.

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php

Comment: i have a little problem again, how do I query the database using the value from the GET variable? the $name is the variable from the $_GET['fname'].

Comment: `$sql=("SELECT ID,fname,mname,lname, from emp_tbl where fname = '%" .$name. "%'"); `

Comment: `("SELECT ID, fname, mname, lname FROM emp_tbl WHERE fname = '" . $name . "';")` should work. Having said that, this is a very unsafe way to use SQL and leaves your site vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

For example, I could go to your form and type in the name field: `'; DROP TABLE emp_tbl; 'testing` and it would process this as a part of your query and delete your table.

Comment: To avoid this, you can simply use `mysql_real_escape_string($name)` in place of `$name`, but if your application uses the database a lot you're probably better off using an ORM.

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] might be a good use here if you want to handle this data on your index.php page. If you'd like to pass it to view.php, action should be:

```
<form action="view.php" method="POST"></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a pagination class? Look this: http://phpsnaps.com/snaps/view/php-pagination-class/ PS. mysql is deprecated, use mysqli.

Comment: tnx... the forum already reminded me of using mysqli instead. But the problem is im still figuring out cause im still learning. But I saw pagination is good practice, ill experiment on that later on :D